# Django form blank=False

Tags: django, forms, validation

Currently, if a field is required, this can be enforced via the blank = False argument, such as:

**models.py**

```
address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False,blank=False)
```

However, the validation is performed prior to the POST action, yielding something like this when trying to submit the form containing an empty field:

[image: Example 1]

I would prefer the validation to be done during the post step, like this:

**models.py**

```
address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=False,blank=true)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(AddressForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['address1'].required = True
```

And this yields the following result when trying to submit the form containing an empty field:

[image: Example 2]

But the problem with this, (as far as I can tell) is that I need to explicitly state the `required` attribute for each field on a case-by-case basis.

Is there any way that I can associate `blank=False` as being representative of the `required=True` attribute, suppressing the first form validation (above), in favour of the second?

Comment: What? I don't understand your problem. Why you want something contradicting. `Model.Field.blank` equivalent to `not Form.Field.required`

Comment: Ok, like this, I want to specify blank = False (at the model level), yet I DON'T want that popup box "Please fill out this field", rather, I want the red highlighted "This field is required" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModelForm runs form validation, then model validation:

> There are two main steps involved in validating a ModelForm:
>
> Validating the form
>
> Validating the model instance

So you have to manually add the extra form validation that you want before the inherited model validations.
However, default ModelForm field for blank field is already required:

> If the model field has blank=True, then required is set to False on
> the form field. Otherwise, required=True

You can change the error message. If you use this additional validations a lot, you can use a Mixin:

```
class BlankToRequiredMixin(object):
   def set_required(self):      
      model = self._meta.model
      for field_name,form_field in self.fields.iteritems():
          if not model._meta.get_field(field_name).blank:
              form_field.error_messages={'required': 'This field is required'} # to make it required in addtion to non-blank set .required=True
```

Then, to set `required=True` for all fields that are non-blank in the model:

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm,BlankToRequiredMixin):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(AddressForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.set_required()
```

In a similar way you can add other validations to the form fields, based on the model validation attributes. For the appearance, change the widget and set the field widget in the mixin.

Comment: The 'Please Fill Out This Field' popup box is still appearing, shouldn't this mixin set `blank = True` somewhere for the model fields?

Comment: in other words moving from `blank=False,required=False` to `blank=True,required=True`

Comment: Changing field attributes requires migrations. Blank=True has a disadvantage, it will not warn you if you forget required=True.

Comment: Well how do I stop the popup "Please fill out this field", which is triggered by `blank=False`, in favour of the validation which takes place when `required=True`

Comment: Updated the answer. What do you use the shows the pop-up in the first place?

Comment: I want the default behaviour when `blank=False` to be the same as what is delivered when `blank=True, required=True`. The first presents a popup, the second presents the error messages in the field helper. Not sure how I can be clearer.

Comment: I asked what library is creating the pop-up. It's not django, it's a widget or something. Your problem happens because when blank=True the form invalidate the field with the model, and this library or whatever is not triggered. If this is the case, then manually adding the widget to the field in the mixin will solve the issue.

Comment: Turns out that this popup was coming from browser -- chrome to be specific, as it didn't appear in safari etc... adding novalidate="novalidate" attribute to the form prevents this from happening. This means your mixin works perfectly. Cheers.

Comment: ie `<form method="post" class="form" novalidate="novalidate">`